# Copy data between postgres databases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I need, as a one-off, to copy data from one table in a PostgreSQL database to the corresponding table in a different database.  There's not that much data: about 2500 rows, 8 columns (some numeric, some varchar).

My first thought was to simply `pg_dump -a -t table -f output.file` and then `pg_restore` on another database.  However, as it turned out, the versions of `pg_dump` and the source server do not match - and I have no control over versions, so upgrading is not an option:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.1.2; pg_dump version: 9.0.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Unfortunately, with version 9 of Postgres, option `-i` (ignore version) is not longer available. I **do** know what I am doing, but it still wouldn't let me (naturally).

What other options do I have?

Comment: Did you try to use a plain text dump (`pg_dump -Fp`)? (which is a SQL script that is "restored" using `psql`)

Comment: `pg_dump` aborts as soon as it encounters version mismatch without looking at anything else

Comment: It only stops if you're going the wrong way.  I.e. pg_dump from 8.4.13 can dump from 8.3.x with no errors.

Comment: Please read my question carefully: pg_dump from 9.1.2 does **not** dump data from 9.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`COPY TO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) and `COPY FROM`. Works in either of the versions and is the optimal tool for this.

If you want to use `pg_dump`, you have to use the appropriate version. There are separate executables for each version. On Linux you can get the path of the currently used executable with `which pg_dump`.

Comment: Perfect! `COPY TO` (and `COPY FROM`) is exactly what I've been looking for.